# Pull down combo box not processing the choice

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight

I Have a Silverlight WPF app that shows tabs of data in this case I have a new pulldown of status here is what the pulldown looks like:

[screen shot http://www.mediafire.com/download.php?vkwvj6qq6q6zjoz](http://www.mediafire.com/download.php?vkwvj6qq6q6zjoz)

the code to process this is here: it is not doing it. We want the user to be able to filter the detail view by status in that combo box. any ideas why it would not display anything. i try the only status we are showing the 'NOT STARTED - LATE' and it displays a blank screen.

```
private String _Type;
private String AssessmentType
{
     get { return _Type; }
     set { if (this.SetReferenceProperty("AssessmentType", ref _Type, value)) 
                 { RefreshData(); } 
         }
 }
```

assessment type is defined:

```
private readonly String[] _assessmentType = new String[]   
       { "All", "UnCompleted", "Completed", "Incomplete Late", 
         "NOT STARTED - LATE", "Submitted", "Submitted Late" };

RibbonControlHelper.CreateComboBox("Assessment", "Assessment", 
       "Select Assessment to show.", _assessmentType, (type) => 
            { AssessmentType = type; }))

protected override void RefreshData()
{
        if (FacilitiesAreChanging) { return; }
        Loading = true;
        SchedulesRepository.Details(FacilitySelectionService.SelectedFacilities, 
                                 UnitCode, AssessmentType, StartDate, EndDate,
        (schedules) =>
        {
            var data = new ListCollectionView(schedules);
            data.GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription
                                                             ("FACILITY_KEY"));
            data.GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription
                                                             ("UNIT"));
            Data = data;
            Loading = false;
        });
 }
```

Comment: "I Have a Silverlight WPF app."  Is it Silverlight or WPF?  It is not the same thing.

Comment: its for certain WPF. I thought there is also Silverlight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked into PropertyBinding and DataContext in WPF? There you can use  System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx bind it to the DataSource and everytime the Collection Changes, the ComboBox changes the Conntent-Datat itself without having manualy update every single UI-Controll in a setter.